# Adding selected character/ .gltf model in a-frame

Tags: three.js, aframe, aframe-networked

I'm stuck on one problem.
[image: Example image]

There are three items I've built into the options. So, I want to click on any one of the buttons to change the avatar as per the click.
If anyone selected a male avatar so it should be reflected in others also.
**For example if there are 4 users. And from that 3 are male and 1 is female and the female selected a female avatar. So, she can able to see others as a male avatar and others can see her as a female avatar(.gltf model).**

Is there any way to dynamically add the .gltf model in a-frame and also update it for others?

```
<body>
<!-- ============================ Start Model Selection ==========================  -->
<div class="container" style="z-index: 1; position: fixed">
  <div class="content_container content_container-1">
    <div class="svg">
      <img
        src="https://s2.svgbox.net/illlustrations.svg?ic=selfie-boy"
        alt="Boy"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="content content-1">Boy</div>
  </div>

  <div class="content_container content_container-1">
    <div class="svg">
      <img
        src="https://s2.svgbox.net/illlustrations.svg?ic=selfie-girl"
        alt="Girl"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="content content-2">Girl</div>
  </div>

  <div class="content_container content_container-1">
    <div class="svg">
      <img
        src="https://s2.svgbox.net/illlustrations.svg?ic=my-robot"
        alt="Robot"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="content content-3">Robot</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- ============================ End Model Selection ==========================  -->

<a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA">
  <a-entity environment="preset: forest;  grid: cross"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

This is the code I've written for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://github.com/networked-aframe/networked-aframe#syncing-custom-components) mention syncing custom components (and `gltf-model` is a component),
and it's quite simple. Lets say we want a model with the standard heads:

1. Add the entity with the `gltf-component` to the networked template:

   ```
   <template id="avatar-template">
     <a-entity class="avatar">
       <a-entity class="model" gltf-model></a-entity>
       <a-sphere class="head">
       <!-- The rest of the template definition -->
   ```
2. Add it to the `NAF.schemas`:

   ```
   NAF.schemas.add({
        template: '#avatar-template',
        components: [
          // the default position, rotation, color
          {
            // the model entity has a .model class
            selector: '.model',
            // we want the gltf-model component to sync between clients
            component: 'gltf-model'
          },
   ```
3. Add the model to your local client:

   ```
   <a-entity id="player" camera
            networked="template:#avatar-template;attachTemplateToLocal:false;"
            position="0 1.6 0" wasd-controls look-controls>
     <a-entity class="model" gltf-model="#fox" model-changer></a-entity>
   </a-entity>
   ```
4. Create the `model-changer` component which changes the model when the images are clicked:

   ```
   AFRAME.registerComponent("model-changer", {
     init: function() {
       // nothing special here - change the models when the images are clicked
       const btn1= document.getElementById("btn1")
       const btn2= document.getElementById("btn2")

       // for whatever reason i need to update the model with the actual source, not just the id
       function getAssetSrc(id) {
         return document.getElementById(id).getAttribute("src")
       }
       btn1.addEventListener("click", e => {
         this.el.setAttribute("gltf-model", getAssetSrc(model1))
       })
       btn2.addEventListener("click", e => {
         this.el.setAttribute("gltf-model", getAssetSrc(model2))
       })
     }
   })
   ```

Check it out in [this glitch](https://glitch.com/%7Egftruj-aframe-networked-avatars) - the images should change the models:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm also trying the same thing but not getting where to start to thank you so much for such beautiful code. Let me try, if I face any issues I'll connect to you.